Does EF Core load all properties of an entity before loading the entities in .Include?
I have an entity for which I have property that's dependent on a virtual member. While loading the entity, I am getting the virtual member as null even though I have included it in .Include.
My entity looks like this:
public class Bill
{
    private int _totalQuantityStored;
   
    public static Bill Create()
    {
        var bill = new Bill();
        InitializeVirtualMembers(bill);
    }
    
    private static void InitializeVirtualMembers(Bill bill)
    {
        bill.AllSales = new List<Sales>();
    }

    private Bill()
    {
    }

    [AutoIncrement]
    public int BillId { get; set; }

    public int TotalQuantity
    {
        get
        {
            if (_totalQuantityStored > 0)
            {
                return _totalQuantityStored; 
            }
          
            if (AllSales is null)
            {
                throw VirualMemberNotLoadedException<Sales>(nameOf(AllSales));
            }
  
            return AllSales.Sum(a => a.Quantity);
        }
        
        set => _totalQuantityStored = value;
    }

    public virtual IList<Sales> AllSales { get; private set; }
}

This is the command I use to load my entity:
var bill = context.Bills
                  .Where(b => b.BillId == billId)
                  .Include(b => b.AllSales).SingleAsync(); 

While loading I get VirualMemberNotLoadedException which should have been thrown only when AllSales is null. But since I am including it in .Include i expect it to be non null.
If the replace the exception throwing with return 0; and then look at the bill that I fetched from the database in debug mode I see AllSales have indeed been loaded and is not null, but if I see the same during loading of object while butting debugger on if (AllSales is null) then it is indeed null there.
I would expect EF Core to load all the included entities first and then load the properties of parent entity, or at least call the get of the loaded entities after it has loaded all the Included properties.
Due to this I am unable to move ahead with my current model of having my property be dependent on entity and throwing excepting if property is fetched with default value and the corresponding virtual member has not been loaded.
Edit 1: I have tried with enabling Lazy loading as well, but it's results are similar.
Edit 2: This would work if I do something like
public int TotalQuantity
{
    get
    {
        if (_totalQuantityStored > 0)
        {
            return _totalQuantityStored; 
        }
          
        return AllSales?.Sum(a => a.Quantity) ?? 0;
    }
    set => _totalQuantityStored = value;
}

But in this case I would not know if the value is zero because AllSales was not loaded or it's 0 because actually sum of Quantity is 0.

No. EF loads only what you tell it to. EF generates a SQL query from the entire LINQ query. Include tells EF to eagerly load related entities that aren't otherwise referred to in the rest of the query. If a Select() or Where referred to a related entity's property, the generated SQL would include a JOIN with that table. Did you check the generated query? Why call Include after Where anyway?

Currently my unit tests are not setup to log generated sql, so i cannot verify the generated sql. But i am calling Include because AllSales is not included in where or select, also it is required for TotalQuantity to be calculated in cases it's value in Db is 0.
Keeping Include aside I would expect that if i enabled lazy loading it would automatically load the virtual member. It does but only after calling get of TotalAmount(maybe for change tracking) which caused it to throw exception. (I know this because I tried returning 0 instead of throwing exception and then looking at bill object.

What happens when you use .ToListAsync() instead of .SingleAsync() ?

The result is still the same only difference being bill is a list with only 1 item.

If the following works, that means the null was only being returned only while EF was loading the entity internally. This is not going to happen when you use the entity in your own code, given that you have eager loaded AllSales.
If TotalQuantity returns 0, that means the actual sum of Quantity is 0.
public int TotalQuantity
{
    get
    {
        if (_totalQuantityStored > 0)
        {
            return _totalQuantityStored; 
        }
          
        return AllSales?.Sum(a => a.Quantity) ?? 0;
    }
    set => _totalQuantityStored = value;
}


Previous answer before questions was edited:
I think your TotalQuantity property gets read by EF while it's being loaded. Add a [NotMapped] attribute on it and see if it helps.

I don't want it to be not mapped i want it to be stored in database. I just want that if it's 0 then the value should be calculated based on AllSales.

Then I would say you need a computed column with some sql to calculate it. ie: SELECT SUM([Quantity]) FROM [AllSales] WHERE [BillId] = [Id]

I think so too, ef might be calling the getter while loading up the entity and regarding this not happening in my code, it would be true in this scenario but any other part of code that's loading this along with other properties might not have this .Include(b => b.AllSales). So for those scenarios I want to make sure that if the user has forgot to load the entity then they get a meaningful exception and for tracking if the entity is loaded or not I don't wanna dive into change tracker solutions atm.

Reg, computed column with some sql to calculate it. That is something I am trying to achieve with this column. If I want to get the most updated value then I would just set TotalQuantity to 0 and then would just call getter of this property (which should work if AllSales is loaded or throw exception otherwise)
